# IE8 browser settings in company group policy SCCM

Tags: publishing-site, browser-compatibility, organization-browser

Which of the following IE8 configuration settings might cause an issue for SharePoint (2007 or 2010).

1)  Tools -> Compatibility View Settings, Uncheck "Display iIntranet sites in Compatibility view" and "Display all websites in Compatibility view"

2)  Tools -> Options, General tab, Browser history, Delete, Uncheck "Preserve Favorites website data".

3)  Tools -> Options, Security tab, Select "Internet" zone, Change "Level for this zone" to Medium-Low.

4)  Tools -> Options, Security tab, Select "Local intranet" zone, Change "Level for this zone" to Medium-Low.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you describe what you mean by "issue"?

Related to #1, SharePoint 2007 does not support IE8 unless SP2 has been deployed. As long as your SharePoint 2007 environment is patched to SP2, then IE8 standard view is supported for both SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010, so compatibility should not be required.

Related to #4, Medium-Low is the default setting for Local Intranet, and your internal browsers should be recognizing your SharePoint sites as Local Intranet for them to work properly with Windows Integrated authentication (if that is what you are using).

Comment: I meant rendering problems such as distorted images, pages etc.. thanks for your answer.